# Get String from cell Turn into two string —Add result to Array

Tags: vba

Hi I would like to know how I can capture one string and break it into two different strings.

Cell A1 has:

```
Cat
Dog
```

In the same cell using Alt+Enter

I’m trying to create a larger size array than my example.

Would be:

```
arr(0) = Cat
arr(1) = Dog
```

---

```
Sub CatchTwoString()

Range("A1").Select

Dim myString As String
Dim arr() As Variant

myString = Selection.Text

ReDim arr(0)

arr(0) = myString

MsgBox arr(0)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Split and split on the carriage return:

```
Sub CatchTwoString()

Dim strarr() As String
strarr = Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value, Chr(10))

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(strarr) To UBound(strarr)
    MsgBox strarr(i)
Next i

End Sub
```